# Issue with intersecting two "extruded SVG files"

Tags: modifiers, extrude, wireframe, svg

I have imported two SVG files and extruded them. Now I want to intersect these two objects, however, this boolean modifier doesn't seem to work. The problem seems to be when I import the SVG files, I don't have a clean edge (or surface), consequently, when I extrude, again I don't have a nice surface. I am suspecting this because if I switch to "wireframe" view, there are tones of lines in between. How could I intersect these two objects?

Thanks.

link to the files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XXuA7nQCzkqYvmWarow1dDZSXoiaGDat?usp=sharing

[image: two times a same object]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure, but it seems to me (from what i can tell from the last picture) you are left with the geometry of where the two objects intersect, and the Boolean modifier worked. And I suspect the "tones of lines in between" are normal. Could you maybe try to explain (possibly with an image) what you are trying to achieve, and maybe what that would look like?

Comment: maybe share your file. Have you tried to simplify your meshes?

Comment: I added those files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XXuA7nQCzkqYvmWarow1dDZSXoiaGDat?usp=sharing

there are two files, the idea is to extrude and intersect them, so you can see different faces from different directions.

Comment: Try the remesh modifier on both mesh first then the boolean. If it's not perfect first time, you can use a tiny rescale on one of them.

Comment: "remesh modifier" was really helpful. did most of the job but still having  trouble with intersection.